# Method to remove a caret from list of strings?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, caret

I have a list of strings, and in some, there contains a caret with several random numbers after.

Ex:

```
strings = [MyString1^111,
           MyString2,
           MyString3,
           MyString4^222,
           MyString5^888]
```

The ultimate goal of my program is to remove the caret, but keep the numbers afterwards, and place the strings into a pandas DataFrame, using AverageTime values found in a "dictionary DF", and if not in the "dictionary DF", utilizes 2.91. I attempted to use the replace function, and while it works to eliminate the caret in the list of strings, it fails to be useable in the DataFrame.

Here is what the "dictionary DF" looks like:

```
dictionary = [MyString2 : 3.76,
              MyString3 : 2.66]
```

The two columns in the dictionary are "Name_Of_String", and "AverageTime"

Here's what I have so far:

```
noCaret = []
for i in strings:
    noCaret.append(i.replace('^', ''))


stringsDF = dictionary[dictionary.Name_Of_String.isin(noCaret)]
for i in noCaret:
    if stringsDF['Name_of_String'].str.contains(i).any():
        pass
    else:
        stringsDF.loc[(len(testDFu.Name_Of_String))-1] = [i, np.nan]


stringsDF.fillna(2.91, inplace = True)
stringsDF

stringsDF = [MyString1^111 : 2.91,
             MyString2     : 3.76]
```

When I run this, I receive a partial DataFrame, none of which contain the strings that have carets. How do I resolve this? Thanks!

Edit: I included what the "dictionary DF", and what the outputted stringsDF looks like, and the column names.

Comment: can you provide a sample of `stringsDF`?

Comment: what type is `dictionary`? is it dataframe? bad naming.

Comment: Is the solution below what you are looking for?

Comment: Just for fun, can you try `import io; pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(strings)), sep='^', header=None, names=['string', 'number'])`?

Comment: I need more information to add the "using values found in a "dictionary DF", and if not in the "dictionary DF", utilizes 2.91." feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the result you are looking for, I think: a dataframe with 2 columns, `Name_of_String` and `AverageTime`, all items in `strings` are included, with those that are not in the dictionary with `AverageTime` as 2.91.

Be careful when typing your code, you have switched between `Name_of_String` and `Name_Of_String` in your question, which will produce errors (if they are supposed to be the same column).  Also, dictionaries use `{}` not `[]`, which cannot take `key: value` pairs.

```
import pandas as pd

strings = ['MyString1^111',
           'MyString2',
           'MyString3',
           'MyString4^222',
           'MyString5^888']

noCaret = [x.replace('^', '') for x in strings]

dictionary = {"MyString2": 3.76, "MyString3": 2.66}

stringsDF = pd.DataFrame(data={"Name_of_String": noCaret})
stringsDF["AverageTime"] = stringsDF["Name_of_String"].map(dictionary).fillna(2.91)

stringsDF
#Out: 
#  Name_of_String  AverageTime
#0   MyString1111         2.91
#1      MyString2         3.76
#2      MyString3         2.66
#3   MyString4222         2.91
#4   MyString5888         2.91
```

Comment: Thank you, works great, and much faster than what I had before!